# BeagleBone PWM configuration in kernel space

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, pwm

I'm beginner in kernel module development.

I'm running Debian 8 in BeagleBone Black with cape-universaln loaded. The module pwm_tiehrpwm  is loaded. I can configure pwm signal through the respective /sys/class/pwm/pwmchipN. I have checked the signal using a scope. Everything is working.

My question is how can I configure pwm channel, duty/period, enable and disable in kernel space, in the other words, inside of the kernel module?

Comment: Perhaps look at the PWM driver code.

Comment: I've tried to make changes on PWM driver, but there is a lack of documentation. So, I don't know which functions and which order I should to use. I've made some attempts, but without success, the kernel always crashes.

Comment: @dczanella Look at [Documentation/pwm.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/pwm.txt), especially "Using PWMs" section. For usage examples see `drivers/hwmon/pwm-fan.c` and `drivers/leds/leds-pwm.c`.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I've looked these source codes and they use <.compatible = "pwm-fan"> and <.compatible = "pwm-leds">, but I don't have these devices in my Device Tree configuration, I have <ehrpwmX>. So how can I use this device? Or how can I match the device tree device with my driver?

Comment: @dczanella If you can't modify your board's Device Tree file, you should create and load corresponding Device Tree overlay file with definition of your devices.